# Spring dependency injection doesn't work in ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, bean-validation

I'm trying to use my service into custom ContextValidator annotation using @Autowired. I looking for some help in old questions on SOF but I was unfortunately so I've created is one new. My goal is valid bean's property with annotation @MyId above it.

Here is my code:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { MyIdValidator.class })
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface MyIdSpring {

    String message() default "Invalid ID!";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

Valdiator class:

```
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE, dependencyCheck = true)
public class MyIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyId, TestID> {

    @Autowired
    private ITestService testService;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyId constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(TestID value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        System.out.println(testService);

        return false;
    }
}
```

configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class ValidatorConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        return bean;
    }
}
```

service:

```
@Service
public class TestService implements ITestService { .. }
```

ITestService is always null. Can you please help me to fix it? I am using spring boot 1.5.

Comment: Please show your component scanning configuration, and the packages for each of these objects

Comment: @MichaelPeacock I don't have explicit defined scanning, I have SpringBoot initializer in root and other components in packages below like /service/TestService, /config/ValidatorConfig, ...

Comment: by SpringBoot Initializer, are you saying your main class with the SpringBootApplication annotation is in a parent package of this Service annotated class?

Answer (score 0):

Use **[@Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html)** annotation to tell Spring about your implementation class.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("testService")
private ITestService testService;
```

Comment: service is still null :/

Comment: Is your @ComponentScan includes TestService  class?